# onClick event won't fire

Tags: reactjs

Sorry for somewhat of a duplicate question, but the valid answers I've seen on other posts match exactly what I've tried and I'm a bit lost.  I'm simply trying to get the onClick event for my button to fire.  It doesn't fire, and zero of the code in my handleClickNewQuote method executes.

I'm sure you can tell I'm extremely new to React and this is just a rough draft of my app if you will.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';




class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
      quote: this.quote,
      author: this.author,
      category: this.category
    }
    this.handleClickNewQuote  = this.handleClickNewQuote.bind(this);
    // this.handleClickTweet = this.handleClickTweet.bind(this);
    // this.handleClickSave = this.handleClickSave.bind(this);
  }

  //Fires when app is loaded~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/getQuote').then(response =>{
      this.setState({quote: response.data.quote, 
                    author: response.data.author,
                    category: response.data.category})
    }).catch(console.log)
  }

  //Fires when NewQuote is clicked, makes API call to server and gets data back

  handleClickNewQuote(){
    axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/getQuote').then(response =>{
      this.setState({quote: response.data.quote, 
                    author: response.data.author,
                    category: response.data.category})
    }).catch(console.log)
    console.log("Button is working?");
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div id="main-container">
          <div id="quote-box">
            <p id="quote-text">{this.state.quote}</p>
            <div id="author-name">
            <p id="author-text">{this.state.author}</p>
              <div id="button-box">
                <button type="button" className="button-color" id="save-button">Save</button>
                <button type="button" className="button-color" id="tweet-button">Tweet</button>
                <button type="button" className="button-color" id="new-quote-button"  onClick={() => {this.handleClickNewQuote}}>New Quote</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: to fire a function you need to put `()` at the end. `onClick={() => {this.handleClickNewQuote}}` should be `onClick={() => {this.handleClickNewQuote()}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because in your arrow function in `onClick` you are not returning the `handleClickNewQuote()` function to be ran.

So, if you did the following it would fire:

`onClick={() => this.handleClickNewQuote}`

However, to simplify this even more we could just remove the wrapping function entirely:

`onClick={this.handleClickNewQuote}`